# SQL Server : condition 3PM yesterday

Tags: sql-server, time

I have a query that I need to add a condition/where clause to. Should be within yesterday at 3PM. So I need something like

```
>= DATEADD(hh, -24, GetDate() at 3PM)))
```

So instead of 24 hours ago, the cutoff time should be the previous day at 3PM

Comment: to clarify: within 24 hours (before 3PM) after record was added [AddedDt]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming current datetime is `2017-01-18 12:52:19.170`

```
Select cast(cast(DateAdd(DD,-1,GetDate()) as date) as datetime)+'15:00'
```

Returns

```
2017-01-17 15:00:00.000
```

Comment: Hi.  I just ran: Select cast(convert(int,GetDate()) as datetime)-2+'15:00' and it retirned 2017-01-16 15:00:00.000

Comment: @user2811136 curious. the math should work.  Just updated my answer.